# How to put a chart in an smtp email

Tags: email, charts, smtp

I am looking to include a pie chart in a html smtp email.

I thought about an ASP.NET chart first, but this is on the front end. Then I thought about High Charts but I can't attach the javascript for them. Finally I decided on Google Chart API.

I searched around and found if I put the URL into an image tag it will put the image returned from the URL into my email. But I've done this and am only getting the "alt" text. A bit of googling said I need to make my smtp HTML. But I've done that too and still no image.

```
var mail = new MailMessage();
mail.From = new MailAddress("email@address.com");
mail.To.Add("email@address.com");
mail.Subject = "Chart Test";
mail.Body = "<img src='https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=250x100&chd=t:60,40&cht=p3&chl=Hello|World' alt='chart' />";
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

var smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.Send(mail);
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Ps - This is my first post so be gentle lol

Answer (score 0):

I'd go back a few steps in determining what's wrong with this thing here. First of all, send an e-mail with an image in it full stop. Next, I notice that the source of the image is https. Verify whether that's possible with a simpler HTTPS image. Then, it'd be worthwhile checking if you can even include content from a webserver that isn't your own via e-mail (could have something to do with server settings).

Those 3 steps of debugging will lead to your answer, I hope!

Good luck!

Comment: If you cant "hotlink" to the image, you'll have to send one that's been stored in your own image folder.

Comment: Thanks Harry. I'll have a look at your suggestions. Many thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

some things I see wrong with your approach are:

1: your mail body is an incomplete html document

2: you are linking external content instead of including the image in the email,
external images are often blocked by spam filters etc.

3: you are sending what might be confidential data to google

4: your chosen pie chart is not circular is this a deliberate attempt to mislead?
Is the proportion relative to the inked area, 
visible subtebded angle, pre-tranformation subtebded angle,
and if so it the transformation oblique or perspective?

urnortunately I don't know enough about asp mail to give details of how to fix that
but for best results you should:

1> send valid HTML

2> generate the graph on your server and send it and the html together in the email as multipart-related

3> combine that and a text a version (using multipart alternative)

4> be sure to generate a circular pie chart, If you want it to look good (especially when printed out) use a vector format like SVG instead of a pixel format.